# BigtableIO Read keys with a given prefix

Tags: apache-beam, bigtable, apache-beam-io

I'm looking for the best way of reading all the rows with a given prefix. I see that there is a `withKeyRange` method in `BigTableIO.Read` but it requires you to specify a start-key and and an end-key. Is there a way to specify reading from a prefix?

Answer (score 1):

Since keys are lexicographically ordered, a given prefix can be converted to a start-key and an end-key. For example, words starting with "apple" can be found using "apple" as the start-key and "applf" as the end-key.

See [this issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/issues/1790) for some more details on computing the end-key.

This seems like it could be a reasonably useful contribution to Beam. Please consider filing a Jira issue suggesting it and possibly even contributing it!